# Cannot Implicilty Convert Type - Autofac C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a fairly simple ASP.NET MVC app that I am trying to resolve some dependencies in my controller. I have casting problems with `List` and I am not sure what to do at this moment. I have read about the `Resolve()` method with Autofac, but again I am not sure if this will resolve my particular issue.

Here is my controller code:

```
public class NumbersController : Controller
{
    private INumbersModel _model;
    private INumbersBusinessLayer _numbersBusinessLayer;
    private IEnumerable<INumbersModel> _modelList;

    public NumbersController(INumbersModel model, IEnumerable<INumbersModel> modelList, INumbersBusinessLayer numbersBusinessLayer)
    {
        _model = model;
        _numbersBusinessLayer = numbersBusinessLayer;
        _modelList = new List<INumbersModel>(modelList);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        _modelList = _numbersBusinessLayer.AllNumbers.ToList();
        return View(_modelList);
    }    

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        _model = _numbersBusinessLayer.AllNumbers.Single(n => n.ID == id);
        return View(_model);
    }
}
```

Here are my two interfaces:

```
public interface INumbersBusinessLayer
{
        IEnumerable<NumbersModel> AllNumbers { get; }

        void AddNumbers(NumbersModel model);
        void DeleteNumbers(int id);
        void UpdateNumbers(NumbersModel model);
}

public interface INumbersModel
{
        int ID { get; set; }
        bool IsValid { get; set; }
        string Numbers { get; set; }
        string Order { get; set; }
        string Time { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my container config:

```
public static void ConfigureDependencyInjection()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // ...or you can register individual controlllers manually.
    builder.RegisterType<NumbersController>().InstancePerRequest();

    // register models
    builder.RegisterType<NumbersModel>().As<INumbersModel>();
    builder.RegisterType<List<NumbersModel>>().As<List<INumbersModel>>();
    builder.RegisterType<NumbersBusinessLayer>().As<INumbersBusinessLayer>();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

In the browser I get this error:

> The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BusinessLayer.NumbersModel]' is not assignable to service 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[BusinessLayer.INumbersModel, BusinessLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

Comment: Comment this line builder.RegisterType<List<NumbersModel>>().As<List<INumbersModel>>(); and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to register your `INumbersBusinessLayer`, since that is the only thing you actually need to inject into your controller.

Furthermore, change `INumbersModel` to a `class`, so you can use it.

So your controller then looks like this:

```
public class NumbersController : Controller
{
    private INumbersBusinessLayer _numbersBusinessLayer;

    public NumbersController(INumbersBusinessLayer numbersBusinessLayer)
    {
        _numbersBusinessLayer = numbersBusinessLayer;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var  modelList = _numbersBusinessLayer.AllNumbers.ToList();

        return View(modelList);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var model = _numbersBusinessLayer.AllNumbers.Single(n => n.ID == id);

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then you can simplify your AutoFac config:

```
public static void ConfigureDependencyInjection()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    // ...or you can register individual controlllers manually.
    builder.RegisterType<NumbersController>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterType<NumbersBusinessLayer>().As<INumbersBusinessLayer>();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

and change your interface to a class:

```
public class NumbersModel
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    bool IsValid { get; set; }
    string Numbers { get; set; }
    string Order { get; set; }
    string Time { get; set; }
}
```

Since your businesslayer interface already expects `Numbersmodel`, but not `INumbersmodel`, no changes are needed there.

Comment: Ah that's great thanks, all is working fine now.  So, I'm a little confused as to why we are registering `builder.RegisterType<NumbersController>().InstancePerRequest();` if I am not passing it into the constructor anymore?  Is it because `INumbersBusinessLogic` depends on it?

Answer (score 1):

Only two parameters require to be injected

```
        private INumbersModel _model;
        private INumbersBusinessLayer _numbersBusinessLayer;

        public NumbersController(INumbersModel model,INumbersBusinessLayer numbersBusinessLayer)
        {
            _model = model;
            _numbersBusinessLayer = numbersBusinessLayer
        }
```

and no need to register a list of  NumbersModel, comment this line and try again

```
  builder.RegisterType<List<NumbersModel>>().As<List<INumbersModel>>();
```